# Is this an adequate place to ask for simplifications on mathematical concepts?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions

I'm not a professional mathematician nor a skilled amateur mathematician, but I have interest in knowing what is the purpose of some mathematical subjects in a simple and clear way, accessible to a layman. (eg: Clifford A. Pickover's books). Can I ask such a thing on MSE?

Comment: I think you mean "an appropriate place", not "an adequate place". :-) [And the answer is yes: as long as your question is specific enough, such questions are most welcome!]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure, but try to keep your questions focused. If a reasonable answer to your question would consist of a book, you're asking for too much. If a reasonable answer to your question would consist of a Wikipedia article, you should at least read the Wikipedia article first and ask questions about whatever's unclear in it.